How can I merge the edges of a series of squares with space between them, so that they become a grid?
I used the buffer function to create a grid of squares around a grid of points that I extracted from a NetCDF file. I did this to keep the geometries of my grid and my spatial data aligned. However, I now have an issue where there are small spaces between the squares, and I am struggling to find a simple way to fill them:
my grid so far
I thought about just manually changing the buffer length so that they align, but am worried about creating many slithers in the process. Is there a function I can use to expand the squares so that there is no space between them, without generating slithers/overlaps?
Alternatively, if there is another way to construct a grid using grid points as centroids I would love to hear it.
I hope this makes some sense. I am very new to QGIS so still figuring this out.
Cheers
Tom
